# Why the name of my models are not respected during the insert

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new on mongoose, i tried to insert some datas, but when i look on rockmongo, the model supposed to be "User" is "users", "Stat" is "stats" etc...

Here are the Schemas:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    facebook_id: String,
    facebook_token: String,
    img: String,
    email: String,
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var StatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    detail: {
        right: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}],
    wrong: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}],
        score: Number
    },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var User = db.model('User', UserSchema);
var Stat = db.model('Stat', StatSchema);
```

and this code create the "users" and "stats" collections:

```
    var U1 = new User({ username: "toto", facebook_id: req.params.facebook_id, facebook_token: req.params.facebook_token })
    U1.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
        console.log('U1 save error');
        var S1 = new Stat({ user_id: U1.id })
        S1.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
                console.log('S1 save error');
        });
    });
```

Why ? Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default behavior is to use the lower-cased, pluralized version of the model name as mostly described in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model) (it doesn't mention  the lower-cased part).

You can provide your own collection name as a third parameter to `model` if you want something else:

```js
var User = db.model('User', UserSchema, 'User');
var Stat = db.model('Stat', StatSchema, 'Stat');
```